# How can I check if a value exists with twig?

Tags: php, twig

I checked if my value exists before printing:

```
{% if address.company|length %}{{ address.company}}{% endif %}
```

But still I get an error message:

> Key "company" does not exist as the array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default filter you can easily verify if a `company` exists and is not empty simultaneously:

```
{% if address.company|default %}
    The company is not empty
{% else %}
    The company is empty.
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `empty` [twig function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/empty.html):

```
{% if address.company is not empty %}
    {{ address.company }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Did you read how this test works? For instance if the `company` object implements the `__toString()` method this test will return true if anything is returned from it. Simple `{% if address.company %}` would be much better.

Comment: "For objects that implement the Countable interface, empty will check the return value of the count() method.

For objects that implement the __toString() magic method (and not Countable), it will check if an empty string is returned." 
Apparently the object `company` is an array so my method is ok no ?

Comment: Nope, the `address` is an array and the key `company` is missing. Anyway it's a bad idea to use this test anyway unless you know exactly how it works in detail. As to my first comment, it should be `{% if address.company|default %}` of course, I cannot edit the comment anymore.

Comment: I didn't know about `default` and read the question too fast. Maybe I should go to lunch. thx for this new filter anyway